# primefaces showcase deployed on tomcat style not loaded

Tags: primefaces

primefaces showcase deployed on tomcat style  not loaded

Downloaded the source code from below link branch 8.0
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-showcase

deployed in tomcat the site is misalligned the styles are not loaded see image attached.
what i am missing why the site is not aligned.

[image]

TOMCAT: NO errors in tomcat logs

Glassfish : Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: java.lang.NullPointerException. Please see server.log for more deta

Wildfly : {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"primefaces-8.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.webapp.FileUploadChunksServlet from [Module \"deployment.primefaces-8.0-SNAPSHOT.war\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.webapp.FileUploadChunksServlet from [Module \"deployment.primefaces-8.0-SNAPSHOT.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}

As long as it deploys in one of the server i am good to go.

Comment: Can you see any error, inspecting your browser console? Have you checked the related questions?

Comment: How did you build the showcase "mvn clean package" to build a WAR?

Comment: build inside eclipse ... mvn clean and mvn build

Comment: TOMCAT : there is no error Tomcat log

Comment: In Wildfly : {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"primefaces-8.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.webapp.FileUploadChunksServlet from [Module \"deployment.primefaces-8.0-SNAPSHOT.war\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.webapp.FileUploadChunksServlet from [Module \"deployment.primefaces-8.0-SNAPSHOT.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}

Comment: In Glassfish : Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: java.lang.NullPointerException. Please see server.log for more deta

Comment: As long as it works in one of the server i will take it from there....

Comment: what does _"Please see server.log for more data"_ restult in? And sure there is nothing visible in the tomcat logs? Hard to believe

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first thing you did is check if `org.primefaces.webapp.FileUploadChunksServlet` is actually in the PrimeFaces 8 jar and noticed it is not there. Then you checked the [PrimeFaces 8 tag in the source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/8.0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/webapp) of PrimeFaces and noticed it is also not there. Then you checked the [PrimeFaces Master (8.0.x) and noticed it IS there](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/tree/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/webapp) Then you checked the PrimeFaces showcase source to see if there, [besides the 8.0.x branch](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-showcase/tree/8.0.x) there is a 8.0 tag and noticed tere is not. So your conclusion was that the 8.0.x showcase is up to date with the master and an explicit version of the showcase at the time of releasing PrimeFaces 8.0 is missing.

So you then decided you have three options

- In the showcase source, go to the point in time of releasing PF 8 and download the source of that 'snapshot'
- File an issue in the PrimeFaces showcase https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-showcase/issues to request a tag to be made (maybe in retrospect even)
- Do both

You then decided to do both and was happy because you could run the showcase locally and made the world a better place since you helped others in the future when the wanted to use the showcase source with a PrimeFaces community release.

Comment: I created an 8.0 Tag here: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-showcase/releases/tag/v8.0

Comment: this works my friend thank you very much for your help.

Comment: FYI : it still did not get deploy in Glassfish and Wildfly thats a problem for another day. IT DEPLOYED FINE IN TOMCAT ---- thanks again

Comment: Showcase deploys fine for me in Wildfly 16 and 19, no problem at all